# Node.js - animate or change colour when new data pushed in?

Tags: jquery, node.js

I'm using a simple code as below for retrieving the data from database using node.js.

What I would like to achieve is that when the new data or the existing data change and are pushed to the webpage I need them to animate or change the colour for only that particular one. How do I go about it?

Any help is much appreciated.

code:

```
// creating a new websocket
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');
// on message recived we print the new data inside the #container div
socket.on('notification', function (data) {
  var usersList = "<div id='aaa'>";
  $.each(data.users,function(index,user){
    usersList += "<p>" + user.users + "</p>";
  });

  usersList += "</div>";    
  $('#container').html(usersList);
});
```